# How to speed up request?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, firebird

I have a Firebird 3.0 database.

My request:

```sql
SELECT 
    CAST(ls.LC_FKey as varchar(15)) Ident
     , CAST(BD_Date as varchar(15)) OrderDate
     , CAST(bill.LCS_Sum as varchar(30)) Amount
     , CAST(bill.LCS_UU_Key as varchar(15)) UniqueNumber
     , CAST((SELECT FIRST 1 OR_PAY_DATE FROM OPL_REESTR opl WHERE opl.OR_LICH = ls.LC_FKey AND opl.OR_PAY_DATE BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND  '2022-06-30') as varchar(15)) OplDate
     FROM Bank_date
LEFT join Licco_sum_now bill ON bill.LCS_PayIdTo = BD_Key and LCS_Type = 6
LEFT JOIN Licco_adres ls ON ls.LC_Key = LCS_LC_Key
where BD_Date BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-30' AND ls.LC_FKey is not NULL
```

the query works for a very long time, is it possible to optimize it somehow?

Comment: What is the plan or explained plan of the query? What is the DDL of the tables? What indexes exist?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.